# While using request validation class through Laravgel API, Error Call to a member function validated() on null

Tags: laravel, api, validation, request

I am using Laravel Request validation class  to validate input through API
[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests)

I implemented as it is mentioned in documentation and got the following error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function validated() on null

The only difference I feel that they submit a form from a web and I am making a request from postman.

It's been a couple of hours, no clue yet. any help, please?

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserTypeRequest extends FormRequest
{        
  public function authorize()
  {
    return true;
  }

  public function rules()
  {
            return [
                'user_type' => 'required',
            ];
        }
    }
```

Calling validation in controller:

```
$this->user_type_request = new UserTypeRequest();
$this->user_type_request->validated();
```

It should be validation input filed coming from the api, instead its showing null in lavatorial

Answer (score 0):

Try and pass the form request via Dependancy injection:

```
public function store(UserTypeRequest $request)
{
    $var = $request->validated();

    ...
}
```

Creating a new form request probably is not validating the previous request (or getting the validation response from the previous request).